# I need an excel formula that sums a range (a5..a59) but depending on the second range (b5..b59) x=100% or .8 = 80%

Tags: excel-formula

I can not figure out what formula I need to do that will sum a range (a5..a59) but depending on the second range (b5..b59) x=100% or .8 = 80%

i.e.
formula in cell 4

```
a5=20   b5=x   
a6=30   b6=x
a7=50   b7=.8
```

results = c4=90

```
20
30
40
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I am trying to use this formula and everywhere there is an x it gives the total (84) so that is summed multiple times. so instead of a total of 84 I am getting 536.
  
  =SUM(IF('Projects active'!$S$5:$S$59="x",SUMIF('Projects active'!$S$5:$S$59,"x",'Projects active'!G$5:G$59),'Projects active'!G$5:G$59*'Projects active'!$S$5:$S$59))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you need is [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).

In this case, it would be `=SUMPRODUCT(A5:A59,B5:B59)`

**EDIT :**

If you need to consider x being equal to 100%, you can use `{=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B3,IF(C2:C3="X",1,C2:C3))}`
Please note this is an array formula, it needs to be validated with ctrl + shift + enter

Comment: Would x need replacing with 1?

Comment: I edited my answer. However, you could also consider adding a third column with a formula such as =IF(B2="X",1,B2)*A2, and spread it to the bottom of your formula range. You could then just sum the result.

Comment: Thank you so Much! Appreciate you taking the time to reply. I tried using sumproduct but could not figure it out and moved on.

Comment: Like it, plus 1.

Comment: Nice approach! Ctrl+shift+enter is not needed with Sumproduct, which is an array-formula in previous versions as well. Translated to the data of the post it would be: `=SUMPRODUCT(A5:A59,IF(B5:B59="X",1,B5:B59))`